# Android fields appear behind title

Tags: java, android

This is what I get :[image: Android emulator]

This is the code:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#0099cc"
tools:context=".LoginActivity"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<!--
     The primary full-screen view. This can be replaced with whatever view
     is needed to present your content, e.g. VideoView, SurfaceView,
     TextureView, etc.
-->

<!--
     This FrameLayout insets its children based on system windows using
     android:fitsSystemWindows.
-->

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:text="@string/UNstring" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textPassword"
        android:text="@string/PWstring" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/LIbutton" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: You can put a top padding in your second linearLayout to get some space for your action bar.

Comment: Do you want the title not shown or the fields underneath the title??

Comment: I want the title. I actually added a top padding

Answer (score 0):

Add android:marginTop attribute to the first element to bring it down.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want the actionbar? 
If not you can hide it.

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) { 
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 
getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);  
setContentView(R.layout.login);
}
```

And in manifest

```
Android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar
```